# Test WAN access to our local area network after opening the DMZ

Tags: dmz

On our router we have recently opened a port. We want to test whether those outside our local area network are able to obtain access. How can we do this?

Unfortunately, we do not have a connection to anything other than our local area network. We thought that perhaps we website exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a product or service recommendation, which we don't do. Additionally, I can't imagine a (legit) business model that would make money hosting a port scanner. Kidz, amirite?

Helpful answers : Take your laptop and go to Starbucks. Or log into a remote server at a hosting service like AWS or Azure. Or log into your home machine remotely using LogMeIn or Chrome Remote Desktop or one of dozens of other options and try it from there.